# jQuery: Why my contains() is not case sensitive?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use the contains() function on my code and I need it to be case sensitive, which is supposed to be, but it's not. 
Whether I type

```
$("keyword:contains('{Keyword:')")
```

or

```
$("keyword:contains('{KeyWord:')")
```

It still works. What am I doing wrong?
This is my JsFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/463834/

Thank you

Comment: added an answer see if it helps

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there an “exists” function for jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31044/is-there-an-exists-function-for-jquery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`if ($("keyword:contains('{Keyword:')")){ ... }` isn't matching against any conditional, and is simply returning a non-false value, so it triggers on everything (the `var keyword = $("#message > p").text();` is targeting an arbitrary element.

The `:contains` selector should be used to target the specific element.

```js
$("div.message > p:contains('{KeyWord:')").text(
  $("div.message > p:contains('{KeyWord:')").text().replace(/{keyword:/gi, "").replace(/}/gi, "")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="message">
  <p>{KeyWord:This is a headline}</p>
</div>



<div class="message">
  <p>{Keyword:This is a headline}</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to check the `$("keyword:contains('{Keyword:')").length` rather than `$("keyword:contains('{Keyword:')")` in the `if()` condition

```js
var keyword = '';
var elm = $("#message > p:contains('{Keyword:')");
if (elm.length) {
  keyword = elm.text().replace(/({Keyword:)/gi, "");
  keyword = keyword.replace(/}/gi, "");
  $("#message > p").text(keyword);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="message">
  <p>{Keyword:This is a headline}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: It dowan't seem to work. But thank you for your help.

Comment: are you saying it does not work correctly ? @CreekBarbara

Comment: Yes it's not working as intended, but I've found a solution by using if (keyword.indexOf("{KeyWord:") >= 0). Thx